# how to access external bootable Linux disk from windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive

I have an **bootable external disk** which a **Linux** is installed on it. I can boot into it and use Linux there. It is a 1TB disk. I think it will be better if I can **also** use it as a storage when I use my **Windows 7 machine**.I plug it in the windows 7 machine. But it cannot show up. Windows 7 says the drive is installed successfully but it is not listed.

Is there a way to make it recongizable by windows 7 and also keep the bootable Linux installation?

I installed the Linux 2 years ago by using a live CD when I bought the external drive. I guess it was formatted as Linux file system? I am not sure though.

**EDIT:**

My case is not a dual boot disk. Mine is a separated external movable bootable USB disk.

I have attached a screen shot about my situation. The one selected is the 1TB external drive. I have another bootable USB drive plugged in and it is listed by the Windows 7.

If I use 3rdparty software, it will allow me to read and write as usual?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your external's filesystem isn't compatible with Windows (generally Ext4 or Ext3 for linux). What you need is a 3rd party driver / software which will give you the ability to read / write on that partition. Several ways are discussed here : http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/ but I advise you to keep your access level as read only because Windows can make a mess of these filesystems while writing.

Answer (score 0):

Your volume is probably not mounted. See [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mount-dismount-drive#1TC=windows-7) for how to mount volumes. If it shows up and say your filesystem is incorrect / your volume is not formatted, then install a ext file system driver, like [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/). It should fix the problem.